# Are there any game/graphics engines for the D programming language?

Tags: d, game-engine

Are there any game/graphics engines for the D programming language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most certainly, and infact there are quite plenty (although at varying stages of maturity). Have a look at the game section on dsource: http://www.dsource.org/projects/

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [DAllegro and DAllegroGL](http://www.dsource.org/projects/dallegro). They are mainly in C/C++ but contain a D language binding.

Answer (score 2):

there are ports for the horde3D engine too, they can be found in the forum of it: [horde 3d homepage](http://www.horde3d.org/)